# Hosts file in windows

Tags: dns, ip, hosts

I was ready about how hosts file are used for DNS resolution. Curious to know what IPs and domain names are there in my system's hosts file, I opened it. I found the file in the path `C:\Windows32\drivers\etc`, there I can see my hosts file. I opened it, but it's all commented. I searched a bit and got to know that is a sample file. Another file will be there in the same folder with an extension of .sam. Indeed, I found the file `Imhosts.sam`. I opened it and this file also is whole commented.
So, I had two doubts here:

- Whenever I try to open any site, my browser always contacts the DNS server because there's no entry in my hosts file?
- Why is it such that my hosts file is all commented? Or am I looking at a wrong file?

Comment: you simply have no entries in *hosts*...The comments help you add entries

Comment: For the second, it's because the hosts file is not normally needed when DNS is available. It's only needed when there is no DNS available or when you need to simplify accessing something that has no DNS name. Windows does not normally use the hosts file. The commented entries are there to demonstrate to you how to create an entry if needed, nothing more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be exact, the `hosts` file can be used for name resolution *instead* of DNS.

If there's nothing in there except for comments that's a good thing. You should only use `hosts` when there's no other, clean solution. Experience shows that outdated and forgotten `hosts` entries can be a major pain.

`lmhosts` is the Windows pendant to WINS NetBIOS name resolution - you most probably don't need that and should stay away from it.