# Using hosts file to rediect to local html file

Tags: hosts

In Windows 10 I'm trying to use the hosts file to redirect to an html file on my local machine:

'''c:\Windows\mystuff\index.html   www.somesite.com'''

I know when I click on "index.com" it opens in the browser, but doesn't work from the hosts file. What's wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hosts file in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48128376/hosts-file-in-windows)   (a HTML file has nothing to do with DNS )

Comment: (This question has nothing to do with what a hosts file is or how it works. It is a specific problem I need to know haw to solve!!)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.